# Подключение к MS ACCESS базе с попыткой создать базу по контексту "FAILED"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ms-access, oledb

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.'
Такую чудесную ошибку я получаю при попытке подконектиться к базе и создать её по контексту.
Однако, я решил проверить, есть ли у меня хоть что-то из данного провайдера. и получил следующее: [image: введите сюда описание изображения] при помощи такого кода:

```
RegistryKey rkACDBKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Classes");

        if (rkACDBKey != null)
        {

            foreach (string subKeyName in rkACDBKey.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                if (subKeyName.Contains("Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Yep ${subKeyName.ToString()}");
                }
            }
        }
```

Строка подключения: 
`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=C:\Users\u.furmanau\Documents\Database2.accdb" providerName="JetEntityFrameworkProvider"/>
  </connectionStrings>`

Какую версию я не подставлял 12 или 16 одна и таже ошибка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я выставлял Debug x86 и x64 всё одно и тоже. Хэлп кто сталкивался)

Comment: А Access установлен? Для OLE, это может наиболее критичным условием, если на машине не установлен, то может выпадать такая ошибка, по крайней мере у меня была подобная проблема и решилась она именно установкой  Access. Фактически тут маленькие и мягкие собирают таким образом деньгу)))

Comment: @Monomax установлен)

Comment: попробуй  OLEDB.12, иногда тоже может подхватываться...